# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 10 String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 10 String or binary data would be truncated

```
insert into Customers (CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
    values
        (3, 'Antonio Moreno Taquería', 'Mataderos 2312', 'México D.F.', 05023,  'Mexico'),
        (4, 'Around the Horn', '120 Hanover Sq.', 'London', 110025, 'UK'),
        (5, 'Berglunds snabbköp', 'Berguvsvägen 8', 'Luleå', 0022,  'Sweden'),
        (6, 'Blauer See Delikatessen', 'Forsterstr. 57', 'Mannheim', 68306, 'Germany'),
        (7, 'Blondel père et fils', '24 place Kléber',  'Strasbourg', 67000, 'France'),
        (8, 'Bólido Comidas preparadas', 'C/ Araquil, 67', 'Madrid', 28023, 'Spain'),
        (9, 'Bon app''', '12, rue des Bouchers',    'Marseille', 13008, 'France'),
        (10, 'Bottom-Dollar Marketse', '23 Tsawassen Blvd.', 'Tsawassen',284, 'Canada')
```

Comment: Maybe because of this ` (9, 'Bon app''', '12, rue des Bouchers', 'Marseille', 13008, 'France'), ` . 'Bon app''' <--- there are three of them ('). But due to limited info, I'm not sure

Comment: The error is clear, you're trying to insert a long string into a short column. You didn't post the table creation script so it's not possible to guess *which* value is causing the problem. Try commenting out lines until you find which one cased the problem. Start by commenting out the first half of the values

Comment: BTW your strings contain non-English characters. You should probably use `nvarchar` fields and Unicode literals (with an N prefix) to avoid conversion errors

Comment: You haven't posted any relevant information yet. It's not possible to guess which column is too short. The only advice one can give is to write a query that returns the maximum size for each column in the data and check which table column is shorter. Something like `select max(len(CustomerID)), max(len(CustomerName)), max(len(Address)), max(len(City)), max(len(PostalCode)), max(len(Country))
from (values ....) t1(CustomerID,CustomerName...)`

Comment: On an unrelated note, it looks like you're treating postal code as a number. Don't do that. They're not numbers, you don't add them together or multiply them. And, for instance, a UK postal code doesn't look like `110025`. It looks like `PO143AU`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wot? My student address at Manchester was `M60 7LH`. Can't you guys agree even on a standard zip code format?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - we used to have variable length phone numbers too but that got aged out of the system as it had to expand for the mobile phone explosion.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this question without the table schema, ie the `CREATE TABLE` statement. The error itself is quite clear, the query is trying to insert a string value into a shorter column. Without the table's definition it's impossible to find out which one it is.

The best one can do is suggest ways to troubleshoot this. The simplest thing would be to just comment out lines until the error goes away.

Another option would be to calculate the maximum length for each column in the data and compare it to the column definitions, eg with :

```
select max(len(CustomerID)) as CustomerID, max(len(CustomerName)) as CustomerName, 
        max(len(Address)) as Address, max(len(City)) as City, max(len(PostalCode)) as PostalCode, 
        max(len(Country)) as Country
from (values 
        (3, 'Antonio Moreno Taquería', 'Mataderos 2312', 'México D.F.', 05023,  'Mexico'),
        (4, 'Around the Horn', '120 Hanover Sq.', 'London', 110025, 'UK'),
        (5, 'Berglunds snabbköp', 'Berguvsvägen 8', 'Luleå', 0022,  'Sweden'),
        (6, 'Blauer See Delikatessen', 'Forsterstr. 57', 'Mannheim', 68306, 'Germany'),
        (7, 'Blondel père et fils', '24 place Kléber',  'Strasbourg', 67000, 'France'),
        (8, 'Bólido Comidas preparadas', 'C/ Araquil, 67', 'Madrid', 28023, 'Spain'),
        (9, 'Bon app''', '12, rue des Bouchers',    'Marseille', 13008, 'France'),
        (10, 'Bottom-Dollar Marketse', '23 Tsawassen Blvd.', 'Tsawassen',284, 'Canada')) 
    x(CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
```

This returns :

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    Address City    PostalCode  Country
2           25              20      11      6           7
```

You'll have to compare those sizes with the column definitions to find out which one is too short.

The query itself has other issues too.

- It contains non-English letters like `é`, `ä` and `å` in ASCII strings.
- It treats post codes as numbers, when they can be anything a country wants them to be. My Manchester zip code was `M60 7LH`. Damien in the comments posted `PO14 3AU`, which Google says is in Fareham. The size is different even in the same country

The table columns should be `nvarchar(...)`, the query should use string literals, ie `N'México D.F.'` instead of `'México D.F.'` and the zip code should be stored in an `nvarchar()` field